# Windows10+VS2015+UWPにおける、空き容量調査について

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-store-apps

いつもお世話になっております。
掲題の通りです。

ディスクの空き容量によって処理を分岐したいと思っております。
使用出来なくなったDriveInfoの代替となるクラス等はあるのでしょうか。

何かご存じのかたいらっしゃいましたら、ご指導のほどお願い申し上げます。

Comment: pgrho様ありがとうございます
SystemReferenceなるものが存在するのですね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`System.FreeSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760719.aspx)プロパティを取得すればよいかと思います。

```
var ad = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current;
var props = await ad.LocalFolder.Properties.RetrievePropertiesAsync(new []{ "System.FreeSpace" });
Debug.WriteLine(props["System.FreeSpace"]);
```